# Google App Engine datastore - adding manually - not letting me

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to manually create entities in my google app datastore through app engine console.  I see the name of my entity but then when I click to add new entries, I get this message:

The kind Institution_Table doesn't exist in the  namespace?

And it won't let me add new ones??  Any ideas??

Also, my local datastore repeatedly gets erased every so often - something must be triggering it but I don't see any option to change this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you first need to create Models in your code to add entities to the datastore.
So in your case, you might create a model in a file called model.py

```
class Institution_Table(ndb.Model):
      '''...properties...'''
```

And then in your console, import that file, create new entities:

```
import model
IT = Institution_Table()
IT.populate(**kwargs)
IT.put()
```

Does that answer your first question?

To answer your second question, by default your datastore writes to a tmp folder on your filesystem which is typically erased every time you restart your computer.

You can change the default storage location - see the GAE Documentation here
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Using_the_Datastore